# Get past transactions on a contract using web3.php

Tags: php, erc721, web3php

I am using web3.php script and need to get minted NFT IDs from a contract.

Solution I think about is to read past contract "transfer" events and get tokenId from its data.
but couldn't find any manual on how to do this with WEB3 PHP or if there is another way to this?

PS: Because of some restrictions on development, we have to use php

PS2: It can be done in seconds using Moralis but we are using a custom chain on our local so cannot use moralis web3 api